# php script Config settings

Tags: php, config

I have found a little script which looks interesting, you can download the svn from google code at 
http://code.google.com/p/streetwire/source/browse/

I am trying to set it up on my xampp localhost install, and there is little documentation, here are the first two lines of the config

```
// Paths
define('VHOST_DIR', '/data/vhost');
define('ROOT_DIR', VHOST_DIR . '/www.streetwire.org');
```

I have tried the following settings but it doesnt seem to work

```
// Paths
define('VHOST_DIR', 'C:/xampp/htdocs');
define('ROOT_DIR', VHOST_DIR . '/streetwirescript');
```

For anyone who has looked at the script, im not sure where to go for the 'start' page of the script either!!

Any thoughts on what should go into Vhost_dir?

Answer (score 1):

Searching through the trunk (http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=root_dir+package%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstreetwire.googlecode.com&origq=vhost_dir&btnG=Search+Trunk), `VHOST_DIR` is only used to define `ROOT_DIR`. It looks like all that matters is that `ROOT_DIR` points to the folder that the script is located in.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that the script doesn't run on Windows.

Comment: ...or whatever uses ROOT_DIR can't handle forward slashes on Win.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set /docs as the document root for this to work. E.g. [index.php](http://code.google.com/p/streetwire/source/browse/trunk/docs/index.php) I assume you've seen [INSTALL](http://code.google.com/p/streetwire/source/browse/trunk/INSTALL) too.

Do you have error reporting on and set to maximum? There's a devsite constant in config that I assume gives error information too. What errors are you getting?